# Не выполняется скролл при динамической вставке элементов

Tags: javascript

Приложенный ниже скрипт выполняет следующее:

При нажатии радио "О", "E", "B", "R" происходит фильтрация по первой букве второго слова. После того, как мы фильтруем, при нажатии на отфильтрованный чекбокс необходимо, чтобы выполнялся скролл к надписи "Контент", но этого не происходит. Подозреваю, что это из-за динамической фильтрации. Прошу помощи.

```js
document.querySelectorAll("input[type='radio']").forEach(el => el.checked=false);
let letters = [];

const itemList = [];

document.querySelectorAll('.productdetails li').forEach((el, i) => {

  const letter = el.innerText.trim().split(' ')[1][0];

  letters.push(letter);

  letters = [...new Set(letters)];
  
  itemList.push({
    id: i,
    content: el.innerHTML,
    letter
  });
  
  const lettersMap = letters.map(el => {
    return `<label class="example-lk"><input class="downers form-check-input" name="b" type="radio" value=${el} autocomplete="off">${el}</label>`
  });

  document.querySelector('.results .tabs').innerHTML = lettersMap.join('')

});

document.querySelectorAll('.tabs input').forEach(tab => {
  tab.onclick = (e) => {
  if(tab.name!=="b") return;
  const FilteredList = itemList.filter(item => item.letter === e.target.value).map(item => `<li>${item.content}</li>`);
  
  document.querySelector('.results .content').innerHTML = FilteredList
      
  e.target.closest(".results").querySelector(".content").classList.add("show");

    const pd = document.querySelector(".productdetails")
    if (pd) {
      pd.remove()
    }
  }


  
});



    
(() => {
  const handler = evt => {
    if (evt.target.checked)
      tabs.scrollIntoView({ block: 'start', behavior: 'smooth' });
  };
  const tabs = document.querySelector('.row');
  for (let cbox of document.querySelectorAll('.wannaup'))
    cbox.addEventListener('change', handler);
})();
```

```css
.tabs {
 border: 1px solid black;
 padding: 10px;
 width: 300px;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">КОНТЕНТ</div>
<div class="results">
<ul class="tabs">

<li>
  <label class="example-lk">
  <input class="downers form-check-input" name="b" type="radio" value="3" autocomplete="off">3</label>
</li>

</ul>
 <ul class="content"></ul>
</div>

<ul class="vmproduct productdetails">
            
                <li class="product-container">
                
                <a href="/3q/noutbuki/gliuchit-zavisaet/3/threeq-omonefivezerotwonh.html" title="3Q OM1502NH"><img src="/images/virtuemart/product/resized//resized/3q-om1502nh_0x90.jpg" alt="/resized/3q-om1502nh" class="featuredProductImage"></a>                  <input class="form-check-input wannaup" value="/threeq-omonefivezerotwonh.html" type="radio" name="c"> 
                    <h3 class="prod-list-choose">3Q OM1502NH</h3>
                    
                </li>

            
                <li class="product-container">
                
                <a href="/3q/noutbuki/gliuchit-zavisaet/3/threeq-esonethreezerosixn.html" title="3Q ES1306N"><img src="/images/virtuemart/product/resized//resized/3q-es1306n_0x90.jpg" alt="/resized/3q-es1306n" class="featuredProductImage"></a>                 <input class="form-check-input wannaup" value="/threeq-esonethreezerosixn.html" type="radio" name="c"> 
                    <h3 class="prod-list-choose">3Q ES1306N</h3>
                    
                </li>

            
                <li class="product-container">
                
                <a href="/3q/noutbuki/gliuchit-zavisaet/3/threeq-ogonefivezerothreenh.html" title="3Q OG1503NH"><img src="/images/virtuemart/product/resized//resized/3q-og1503nh_0x90.jpg" alt="/resized/3q-og1503nh" class="featuredProductImage"></a>                    <input class="form-check-input wannaup" value="/threeq-ogonefivezerothreenh.html" type="radio" name="c"> 
                    <h3 class="prod-list-choose">3Q OG1503NH</h3>
                    
                </li>

            
                <li class="product-container">
                
                <a href="/3q/noutbuki/gliuchit-zavisaet/3/threeq-esoneonezerofiven.html" title="3Q ES1105N"><img src="/images/virtuemart/product/resized//resized/3q-es1105n_0x90.jpg" alt="/resized/3q-es1105n" class="featuredProductImage"></a>                  <input class="form-check-input wannaup" value="/threeq-esoneonezerofiven.html" type="radio" name="c"> 
                    <h3 class="prod-list-choose">3Q ES1105N</h3>
                    
                </li>

            
                <li class="product-container">
                
                <a href="/3q/noutbuki/gliuchit-zavisaet/3/threeq-esonezerozeroonen.html" title="3Q ES1001N"><img src="/images/virtuemart/product/resized//resized/3q-es1001n_0x90.jpg" alt="/resized/3q-es1001n" class="featuredProductImage"></a>                  <input class="form-check-input wannaup" value="/threeq-esonezerozeroonen.html" type="radio" name="c"> 
                    <h3 class="prod-list-choose">3Q ES1001N</h3>
                    
                </li>

            
                <li class="product-container">
                
                <a href="/3q/noutbuki/gliuchit-zavisaet/3/threeq-esonefourzerosixn.html" title="3Q ES1406N"><img src="/images/virtuemart/product/resized//resized/3q-es1406n_0x90.jpg" alt="/resized/3q-es1406n" class="featuredProductImage"></a>                  <input class="form-check-input wannaup" value="/threeq-esonefourzerosixn.html" type="radio" name="c"> 
                    <h3 class="prod-list-choose">3Q ES1406N</h3>
                    
                </li>

            
                <li class="product-container">
                
                <a href="/3q/noutbuki/gliuchit-zavisaet/3/threeq-elonezerozerofourn.html" title="3Q EL1004N"><img src="/images/virtuemart/product/resized//resized/3q-el1004n_0x90.jpg" alt="/resized/3q-el1004n" class="featuredProductImage"></a>                 <input class="form-check-input wannaup" value="/threeq-elonezerozerofourn.html" type="radio" name="c"> 
                    <h3 class="prod-list-choose">3Q EL1004N</h3>
                    
                </li>

            
                <li class="product-container">
                
                <a href="/3q/noutbuki/gliuchit-zavisaet/3/threeq-omonefivezerotwonh.html" title="3Q OM1502NH"><img src="/images/virtuemart/product/resized//resized/3q-om1502nh_0x90.jpg" alt="/resized/3q-om1502nh" class="featuredProductImage"></a>                  <input class="form-check-input wannaup" value="/threeq-omonefivezerotwonh.html" type="radio" name="c"> 
                    <h3 class="prod-list-choose">3Q OM1502NH</h3>
                    
                </li>

            
                <li class="product-container">
                
                <a href="/3q/noutbuki/gliuchit-zavisaet/3/threeq-esonezerozeroonenn.html" title="3Q ES1001NN"><img src="/images/virtuemart/product/resized//resized/3q-es1001nn_0x90.jpg" alt="/resized/3q-es1001nn" class="featuredProductImage"></a>                  <input class="form-check-input wannaup" value="/threeq-esonezerozeroonenn.html" type="radio" name="c"> 
                    <h3 class="prod-list-choose">3Q ES1001NN</h3>
                    
                </li>

            
                <li class="product-container">
                
                <a href="/3q/noutbuki/gliuchit-zavisaet/3/threeq-oeonefivezeroonenh.html" title="3Q OE1501NH"><img src="/images/virtuemart/product/resized//resized/3q-oe1501nh_0x90.jpg" alt="/resized/3q-oe1501nh" class="featuredProductImage"></a>                  <input class="form-check-input wannaup" value="/threeq-oeonefivezeroonenh.html" type="radio" name="c"> 
                    <h3 class="prod-list-choose">3Q OE1501NH</h3>
                    
                </li>

            
                <li class="product-container">
                
                <a href="/3q/noutbuki/gliuchit-zavisaet/3/threeq-ononefourzerothreen.html" title="3Q ON1403N"><img src="/images/virtuemart/product/resized//resized/3q-on1403n_0x90.jpg" alt="/resized/3q-on1403n" class="featuredProductImage"></a>                    <input class="form-check-input wannaup" value="/threeq-ononefourzerothreen.html" type="radio" name="c"> 
                    <h3 class="prod-list-choose">3Q ON1403N</h3>
                    
                </li>

            
                <li class="product-container">
                
                <a href="/3q/noutbuki/gliuchit-zavisaet/3/threeq-eneightninezeroonen.html" title="3Q EN8901N"><img src="/images/virtuemart/product/resized//resized/3q-en8901n_0x90.jpg" alt="/resized/3q-en8901n" class="featuredProductImage"></a>                    <input class="form-check-input wannaup" value="/threeq-eneightninezeroonen.html" type="radio" name="c"> 
                    <h3 class="prod-list-choose">3Q EN8901N</h3>
                    
                </li>

            
                <li class="product-container">
                
                <a href="/3q/noutbuki/gliuchit-zavisaet/3/threeq-bnonethreezerotwon.html" title="3Q BN1302N"><img src="/images/virtuemart/product/resized//resized/3q-bn1302n_0x90.jpg" alt="/resized/3q-bn1302n" class="featuredProductImage"></a>                 <input class="form-check-input wannaup" value="/threeq-bnonethreezerotwon.html" type="radio" name="c"> 
                    <h3 class="prod-list-choose">3Q BN1302N</h3>
                    
                </li>

            
                <li class="product-container">
                
                <a href="/3q/noutbuki/gliuchit-zavisaet/3/threeq-rsonezerozeroonet.html" title="3Q RS1001T"><img src="/images/virtuemart/product/resized//resized/3q-rs1001t_0x90.jpg" alt="/resized/3q-rs1001t" class="featuredProductImage"></a>                  <input class="form-check-input wannaup" value="/threeq-rsonezerozeroonet.html" type="radio" name="c"> 
                    <h3 class="prod-list-choose">3Q RS1001T</h3>
                    
                </li>

            
                <li class="product-container">
                
                <a href="/3q/noutbuki/gliuchit-zavisaet/3/threeq-ogonefivezerothreenh.html" title="3Q OG1503NH"><img src="/images/virtuemart/product/resized//resized/3q-og1503nh_0x90.jpg" alt="/resized/3q-og1503nh" class="featuredProductImage"></a>                    <input class="form-check-input wannaup" value="/threeq-ogonefivezerothreenh.html" type="radio" name="c"> 
                    <h3 class="prod-list-choose">3Q OG1503NH</h3>
                    
                </li>

            
                <li class="product-container">
                
                <a href="/3q/noutbuki/gliuchit-zavisaet/3/threeq-rsonezerozeroonetn.html" title="3Q RS1001TN"><img src="/images/virtuemart/product/resized//resized/3q-rs1001tn_0x90.jpg" alt="/resized/3q-rs1001tn" class="featuredProductImage"></a>                  <input class="form-check-input wannaup" value="/threeq-rsonezerozeroonetn.html" type="radio" name="c"> 
                    <h3 class="prod-list-choose">3Q RS1001TN</h3>
                    
                </li>

            
                <li class="product-container">
                
                <a href="/3q/noutbuki/gliuchit-zavisaet/3/threeq-euonezerozerofiven.html" title="3Q EU1005N"><img src="/images/virtuemart/product/resized//resized/3q-eu1005n_0x90.jpg" alt="/resized/3q-eu1005n" class="featuredProductImage"></a>                 <input class="form-check-input wannaup" value="/threeq-euonezerozerofiven.html" type="radio" name="c"> 
                    <h3 class="prod-list-choose">3Q EU1005N</h3>
                    
                </li>

                    </ul>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Обработчики события в js связаны с объектами элементов, на которые они повешены. Когда вы вешаете обработчик, то это изменяет состояние именно того, объекта, на который вы его повесили. Если вы удаляете элемент, то вместе с ним удаляется и его обработчик. Новые элементы, добавленные в dom после того как вы уже повесили обработчики на change, не будут вызывать скрол. Они новые, на них обработчик не повешен!

Выхода из ситуации два.

1. Каждый раз, кода добавляете новые элементы на страницу, вешать на них обработчик.
2. Повесить обработчик на общего родителя, воспользовавшись тем, что события [всплывают](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F#%D0%92%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BB%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82_%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B9).

Второй вариант мне кажется более элегантным.

```js
document.querySelector('.content').addEventListener('change', handler);
```

Comment: Благодарю, не додумался

Comment: Через час система позволить вознаградить